# Get a value from a MongoDB document

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection where documents are as following (MongoDB):

```
{
    _id: 'ABPS1001',
    Brand: 'DecNag',
    serial: '2393-829-109',
    resume: [
        {
            status: '1',
            nameAg: 'Gina',
            lastNameAg: 'Saenz',
            coord_id: '1025',
            movDate: '25-10-2016 11:33'
        },
        {
            status: '0',
            techID: '11',
            coord_id: '1025',
            movDate: '30-10-2016 16:29',
            idReplace: 'ABPS1026'
        },
        {
            status: '1',
            nameAg: 'Diana',
            lastNameAg: 'Gutierrez',
            coord_id: '1014',
            techID: '10',
            movDate: '04-11-2016 09:12'
        },
        {
            status: '0',
            techID: '12',
            coord_id: '1014',
            movDate: '30-11-2016 16:25',
            idReplace: 'ABPS1021'
        },
        {
            status: '1',
            nameAg: 'Laura',
            lastNameAg: 'Diaz',
            coord_id: '1012',
            techID: '11',
            movDate: '04-12-2016 11:33'
        },
        {
            status: '0',
            techID: '10',
            coord_id: '1012',
            movDate: '22-12-2016 12:21',
            idReplace: 'ABPS1107'
        },
        {
            status: '1',
            nameAg: '172.27.48.125',
            lastNameAg: '',
            coord_id: '1004',
            techID: '12',
            movDate: '27-12-2016 08:30'
        },
        {
            status: '0',
            techID: '11',
            movDate: '02-02-2017 14:12',
            idReplace: 'ABPS1107'
        }
     ]
 }
```

I need to get the last entry at "resume" from document where _id: 'ABPS1001' instead the whole document. Is there any way of do this using MongoDB sentences instead processing using programming language?

Also, how can I append or remove values to any set of values on "resume" (for instance, if I want to add "coord_id" to the last set on "resume")?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to find answers before posing this question? both of your questions are basic in mongo and you can find how to do it very easily. let me give you a hint: 1. `aggregation` and `filter` . 2. `update`

Comment: Yes I did, but using info I found didn't satisfied my needs. Anyways, I will recheck MongoDB documentation and @dyouberg info, which was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do the first part of your question with aggregation:

```
// Returns last value of the resume array...
// First - Match the document
// Second - Project to slice the last element of the resume array and put it into a new document called lastValue
db.foo.aggregate([
    { $match: {"_id": "ABPS1001"} }, 
    { $project: { lastValue: { $slice: [ "$resume", -1 ] } } }
])
```

Results in:

```
{
    "_id" : "ABPS1001",
    "lastValue" : [
        {
            "status" : "0",
            "techID" : "11",
            "movDate" : "02-02-2017 14:12",
            "idReplace" : "ABPS1107"
        }
    ]
}
```

For the second part you can do a positional update using the '$' operator, [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/)